# Does R^2 has the same property as R?

Tags: equivalence-relations

If R is a relation on set A, define $R^2$ by $aR^2b$ if and only if there exists c with aRc and cRb. If R is reflexive/symmetric/transitive does $R^2$ have the same property ?

I'm not sure how to do this question? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Meelo: Why are you assuming that ***all*** of the mentioned properties are fulfilled by $R$?

Comment: @TeraPeo Show that $R^2=R$!

Comment: @azarel I think the slash-separated list means that **one** of these properties is assumed for $R$, and the question is whether $R^2$ inherits that property. In general, $R^2$ will not be $R$.

Comment: @CareBear In that case I guess there is a counterexample for each property!

Comment: @azarel I don't think so...

Answer (score 2):

I'll be simple-minded
and try to prove it.

Reflexive:
Since $aRa$,
$aR^2a$ immediately.

Symmetric:
If $aRb$ then $bRa$,
we want
if $aR^2b$ then $bR^2a$.
If $aR^2b$
there is a $c$ with
$aRc$ and $cRb$.
Since $R$ is symmetric,
just turn this around to get
$bRc$ and $cRa$
so $bR^2a$.

Transitive:
We want
if $aR^2b$ and $bR^2c$
then $aR^2c$.
From $aR^2b$ and $bR^2c$,
there are $d$ and $e$
such that
$aRd$, $dRb$,
$bRe$, and $eRc$.

Since $R$ is transitive,
if $aRd$ and $dRb$
then $aRb$;
if $bRe$, and $eRc$
then $bRc$.
Therefore,
since
$aRb$ and $bRc$,
$aR^2c$.

A variation on this:
if $R^2$ is an equivalence relation,
is $R$ also?
My guess is not,
but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is reflexive then $R^2$ is also reflexive trivially. Suppose $aR^2b$ and $R$ is symmetric:

$aR^2b\rightarrow$ there exists a $c$ such that $aRc$ and $cRb$. But $R$ is symmetric so  $bRc$ and $cRa$ therefore $bR^2a$.

Now if $aR^2b$ and $bR^2c$ and $R$ is transitive:

$aR^2b\rightarrow$ there is an $e$ , $aRe$ and $eRb$ so by transitivity of $R$ we have $aRb$.
Similarly $bRc$ and therefor $aRc$.Which by definition of $R^2$ implys $aR^2c$.